# Estimating a trickily defined nonlinear function (e.g., via neural networks)

Tags: neural-networks, nonlinear-regression

I have numerical vectors $y$, $a$, $x$, each with length $N\approx 10^6$, representing data from an experiment. Mechanistically, $y$ is related to $a$ and $x$ in the following way ($i\in \{1,\ldots,N\}$):
$$
y_i \sim \sum_{j=1}^N \big( a_i\cdot f(x_i,x_j) - a_j\cdot f(x_j,x_i) \big)
$$
with some nonlinear differentiable function  $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, which I have no other a priori information about. I need to estimate the function $f$ that provides the best fit, i.e. that minimises the error $\sum_{i=1}^N \Big( y_i - \sum_{j=1}^N \big( a_i\cdot f(x_i,x_j) - a_j\cdot f(x_j,x_i) \big) \Big)^2
$.

My idea is to represent $f$ by a neural network (2 input notes, a few hidden nodes, 1 output node). I would initialise a random set of weights and biases, compute the error, and try to iteratively converge to the optimal weights and biases.

Before I dive into this, I wanted to ask if anyone can see an easier way to estimate $f$ by using existing packages (Python/R), rather than me having to implement a custum backpropagation and gradient descend algorithm from scratch. I am also completely open to approaches other than NNs.

//edit: I asked ChatGPT to adapt the Adam gradient descend approach that I usually use in skilearn to my specific problem, using the above error $\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \ldots)^2$ for the loss function - this solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you want to write your own implementation when software packages like TensorFlow and Keras exist?

Comment: I have used these packages for problems where I needed to estimate a function $f$ defined by, say, $y_i \sim f(x_i,x_j)$, but for the more complex setup I've described (sum over lots of summands, in each of which the function appears twice, with swapped arguments), it is not clear to me how I can use a standard implementation.

Comment: Unless you moved to us from the past over a few years ago, there's no need to implement it manually as there are tons of ready implementations. It's in scikit-learn, R, there's TensorFlow, PyTorch, Julia packages, etc, there are so many it'd be hard to list them all.

Comment: But from your description, it's not clear if you need a neural network at all as many other algorithm would likely suffice.

Comment: Just code up the loss & model you want to compute in PyTorch or another library. At this level of generality, there doesn't seem to be anything remarkable about this.

Comment: @Sycorax, Dave, Tim, it's not obvious to me that this can be done with standard frameworks since the loss doesn't decompose across observations.  @ asker, take chatgpt's solution with a ton of skepticism.

Comment: @Sycorax, Dave, Tim, please feel free to post an answer to the question with a code snippet or provide a link to comparable problem (see Ben Reiniger's comment, which summarises my issue well). Naming packages or mentioning that a different algorithm would do a better job, without specifics, does not help me.

Comment: If this is just a programming question, then it's not on-topic.